# How to compile and run pas2php from source code?

Tags: compilation, freepascal, lazarus

I am a student in Computer Science, and I am learning about logic programming with Pascal.

---

I have found an interesting **Pascal to PHP transpiler** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler), **pas2php** (http://www.wascal.net/pas2php/).

On their webpage, they have written:

> Pas2Php will convert Object Pascal to PHP, alowing you to write web applications using Lazarus/FreePascal, and then run the application on a standard HTML/PHP server.
>
> As a guide as to what Pas2Php can achieve... this web page was written in Pascal, and then converted to PHP. (The code is in the source package) Pas2Php uses the Pascal Parse Tree Classes (PasTree) which comes with FreePascal, and therefore the parsing limits are defined by this library. So far, most of the core Object Pascal language features are compete, but there is still a lot of work needed before I''d class this tool as being "ready".');
>
> You can download the lastest source of Pas2Php from this site which includes an example project. **There isn't much documentation, so, if you want to use Pas2Php, you will have to experiment with the code.**

I have downloaded it, but there is no useful information in their documentation. Because I don't understand their documentation, so, tried to compiled it.

I have opened and compiled **project.lpi** with **Lazarus 1.4.0**. Then **index.cgi** has been created on disk. When I run it with **Command Prompt**, it printed into screen:

```
Pas2Php v0.4
Converts Standard Pascal to PHP
Copyright (C) 2014 Derek John Evans

The unit 'index' is up to date.
The unit 'P2PHtml' is up to date.
The unit 'P2PSystem' is up to date.
The unit 'P2PStringList' is up to date.
The unit 'PageColumnRight' is up to date.
The unit 'SiteDefines' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetBuzz' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetContacts' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetCredits' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetGeep' is up to date.
The unit 'HtmlSoftwareList' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetPas2Php' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetPas2PhpExamples' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetPas2PhpFeatures' is up to date.
The unit 'TabSheetWascal' is up to date.

Package conversion complete.
```

Then, my browser go to: **http://localhost:8008/index.php**. They return nothing.

---

**How to compile and run pas2php from source code?**.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to open the project.lpi in project/ with lazarus.

(In response to the edits:)

It seems that the archive also already contained the example converted from pascal to php, and you now generated it again.

So probably you now need to setup your PHP installation and make it find the generate PHP and start playing with it. Good luck!